# no items found with eBay browse api

Tags: httprequest, ebay-api

Beside my HTTP request implementation in the Apollo server, I'm using the *Production* section of the eBay developer sandbox tool.
I try to find items from eBay browse API [/item_summary/search (Docu)](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/buy/browse/resources/item_summary/methods/search). E.g. I request a German specific therm *Märchenbücher* (books of fairy tales). I encode this URI component.

```
https://api.ebay.com/buy/browse/v1/item_summary/search?q="m%C3%A4rchenb%C3%BCcher"&limit=3
```

and I get the response (Code 200)

```
{
   "href": "https://api.ebay.com/buy/browse/v1/item_summary/search?q=%22m%C3%A4rchenb%C3%BCcher%22&limit=3&offset=0",
   "total": 0,
   "limit": 3,
   "offset": 0
}
```

Do I need to pass the site id of Germany (*site id = 77*)?

Is the feature missing to get only German-based search results with API call (s. Browse APIv1_beta.12.0)?

How can I get the same search results as on eBay.de: [58.851 Ergebnisse für Märchenbücher](https://www.ebay.de/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2380057.m570.l1313.TR12.TRC2.A0.H0.XM%C3%A4rchenb%C3%BCcher.TRS0&_nkw=M%C3%A4rchenb%C3%BCcher&_sacat=0)?